# Root Sum Square (RSS) tolerance of parallel resistors

Tags: resistors, parallel, tolerance

I am trying to figure out the formula for RSS-ing two parallel resistors, but for the life of me can't figure this out.

For series resistors it is easy, just $${R_1 + R_2} \pm \sqrt{ dR_1^2 + dR_2^2}$$

But what is it for two parallel resistors where you use the formula $$R_{\text{tot}} = {R_1 \cdot R_2\over R_1+R_2}$$?

I was thinking you just work out \$\small R_1 \cdot R_2 \pm \text{tol}_A\$ and \$\small R_1+R_2 \pm \text{tol}_B\$, then just do the division $$R_{\text{tot}} = {R_1 \cdot R_2\over R_1+R_2}$$ and $$\text{tol} = {\text{tol}_A \over \text{tol}_B}$$ but this is not right? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The search term is "propagation of uncertainty or error": https://www.geol.lsu.edu/jlorenzo/geophysics/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html. Break down each part of the divider equation and apply each rule. You can also just use sums of partial derivatives which is where the rules come from.

Comment: Hi DKNguyen, this is not RSS though. RSS gives a more realistic estimate for the error. This document is talking about Worst Case Analysis (WCA)

Comment: @Edba `but this is not right` - you didn't say what it should be - what should it be?

Comment: Read it more carefully.

Comment: Hi I am talking about Root Sum Square (RSS) analysis which gives a more realistic picture of tolerance e.g. two 1% resistors in series: WCA gives 2% error (add the two tolerances together) where RSS gives 1.414% error ( sqrt(1^2+1^2) ) which is more realistic. How do you do this for two resistor in parallel with different resistances and tolerances? e.g. 100k 1% resistor in parallel with 20k 5% resistor, I know how to work out the WCA tolerance, but what would the RSS tolerance be?

Comment: Convert to conductances and they add. Note that your example values, the 20K adds 25x the uncertainty of the other. In your comment, the 1.414% error is only true for approximately equal resistors; if one R is sufficiently larger (in series) or smaller (in parallel) you can practically ignore the other's tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

> *Does anyone know how to do this?*

If I make a comparison using [worst case analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_circuit_analysis#:%7E:text=Worst%2Dcase%20circuit%20analysis%20is,applied%20to%20each%20circuit%20component.) (with both parallel resistors being very similar in their basic value), it's the same for series resistors too.

So, if you are able to convert a WCA figure to an RSS figure then, the result is the same.

I mention that both resistors should be similar in their basic value  because, that will be the most onerous situation to consider.

**In series**

$$R_{NET} = R_1(1 \pm\Delta)+R_2(1 \pm\Delta)$$ $$= (R_1+R_2)\cdot (1 \pm\Delta)$$

**In parallel**

$$R_{NET} = \dfrac{R_1(1 \pm\Delta)\cdot R_2(1 \pm\Delta)}{R_1(1 \pm\Delta)+R_2(1 \pm\Delta)}$$ $$= \dfrac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\cdot (1 \pm\Delta)$$

Comment: Could anyone tell me why the above has been downvoted. I'd like to fix the answer if there's a mistake but I've probably gone blind to the issue.